# Run elevated command prompt on not booting pc

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, data-recovery

Windows 10 update 1903 crushed the windows installation on my Surface Pro 3. Repair is not working. So I try to backup my files before doing a fresh windows install. For this I use the console provided in recovery mode.

The problem is that I can not access my user files because I am missing the permissions. To take ownership of those files I would need a command prompt with elevated rights.

How can I start a command prompt with elevated rights from recovery mode?

Comment: PS: I would also happily appreciate suggestions on other possibilities on how to backup my data.

Comment: If you connect the hard drive to a different computer (that is already booted into windows), you can take ownership of all the files. I do not know if you have access to another machine but this would be the easiest route to recover your data.

Comment: Unfortunately opening the Surface Pro 3 seems not to be easy.. Maybe this will help you: https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/enable-built-in-administrator-windows-10-recovery-options-advanced/

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing because I don't know the Surface recovery mode, but if it is a normal windows command prompt you could try this:

> powershell -command "start-process cmd -verb runas"

this, in a normal windows environment, would start a command prompt elevated.

In case this is not possible because for example powershell is not available, then you could try to prepare a usb key with a WinPe environment and test the above command from it.

Another option could be to boot surface with a live linux key and try to access your files from there (if the disk is not locked with BitLocker and if surface let you boot from a Linux key, don't know)

If you can boot linux usb key but have issues accessing the files, and if the disk is not bitlocked, you could also create a Clonezilla usb key, boot from it, use it to create on a NAS or remote share the image of the Surface disk, then restore to another disk you have in your hand, then you could access that disk whatever way you want, for example connecting it in usb to another pc

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Boot the computer with windows OS Installation, wait for it to load.

Hold down "SHIFT" and press "F10" and you will have a command prompt with elevated rights!